# How do I place an IN parameter with a LIKE with a RowSet?

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement, rowset

I have fighting to get a IN parameter to work inside of a LIKE statement now for hours!
I am using a CachedRowSet, which I understand should follow the same rules as a PreparedStatement.
Here is the basic query:

```
CachedRowSet cache;
String sql = "SELECT x " +
                "FROM   Y " +
             "WHERE z LIKE '?__'" 

cache.setCommand(sql);
cache.setString(1, "someString");
```

someString is a known id but the database( by the way is PostgreSQL) entry has a unknown 2 char suffix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameter placeholders inside quotes are ignored.  They're interpreted as a literal "?".  If you use a parameter, you must put the placeholder outside quotes in the SQL expression.

But `LIKE` can be compared to any string or any *expression* that produces a string.  For example:

```
SELECT x FROM y WHERE z LIKE (? || '__')
```

Now you could supply "someString" for the parameter, and then it will be concatenated with the constant string `'__'`.